# Message queue with GLIB {issue in receiving message back after posting}

Tags: c, pointers, gtk, glib

This is a very simple message queue that i am trying to understand

I am able to post the message to the queue but when i am trying to receive the message back i am not receiving.

Please guide what is the error. am a noob to C
http://pastebin.com/UqLWKgub

```
            ####MSG.H#######
            #define MAX_MSG_SIZE 5120
            typedef struct
            {
                    int msgType;
                    int msgSize;
                    char msgBuf[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
            }STRUCT_MSG;

            ####msg.c####
            #include <glib.h>
            #include <Msg.h>

            G_LOCK_DEFINE_STATIC (queue_memchunk);
            static GMemChunk   *queue_memchunk = NULL;
            static GTrashStack *free_queue_nodes = NULL;

            STRUCT_MSG *txMsg;

            //mqd_t msgQueueId[6];
            GQueue *msgQueueId[6];

            int PostMessageQ(int channel, int msgType, char *msgBuf, int msgSize)
            {
                    txMsg = (STRUCT_MSG*)malloc(sizeof(STRUCT_MSG));
                    txMsg->msgType = msgType;
                    txMsg->msgSize = msgSize;
                    memcpy(&txMsg->msgBuf[0],&msgBuf[0],msgSize);
                    g_queue_push_head (&msgQueueId[channel], (char *)&txMsg);
                    return 0;
            }

            int PendMessageQ(int channel, STRUCT_MSG *rxMsgptr)
            {
                    gpointer rxMsg;
                    rxMsg = g_queue_pop_head (&msgQueueId[channel]);
                    memcpy(&rxMsgptr[0],&rxMsg[0],sizeof(STRUCT_MSG));
            }


            GQueue*
            g_queue_create (int channel)
            {
              G_LOCK (queue_memchunk);
              msgQueueId[channel] = g_trash_stack_pop (&free_queue_nodes);

              if (!msgQueueId[channel])
                    {
                      if (!queue_memchunk)
                            queue_memchunk = g_mem_chunk_new ("GLib GQueue chunk",
                                                                                              sizeof (GNode),
                                                                                              sizeof (GNode) * 128,
                                                                                              G_ALLOC_ONLY);
                      msgQueueId[channel] = g_chunk_new (GQueue, queue_memchunk);
                    }
              G_UNLOCK (queue_memchunk);

              msgQueueId[channel]->head = NULL;
              msgQueueId[channel]->tail = NULL;
              msgQueueId[channel]->length = 0;
              //msgQueueId[channel] = queue;
              return msgQueueId[channel];
            }

            void
            g_queue_free (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_if_fail (queue != NULL);

              g_list_free (queue->head);

              G_LOCK (queue_memchunk);
              g_trash_stack_push (&free_queue_nodes, queue);
              G_UNLOCK (queue_memchunk);
            }

            void
            g_queue_push_head (GQueue  *queue,
                                               gpointer data)
            {
              g_return_if_fail (queue != NULL);

              queue->head = g_list_prepend (queue->head, data);
              if (!queue->tail)
                    queue->tail = queue->head;
              queue->length++;
            }

            void
            g_queue_push_head_link (GQueue *queue,
                                                            GList  *link)
            {
              g_return_if_fail (queue != NULL);
              g_return_if_fail (link != NULL);
              g_return_if_fail (link->prev != NULL);
              g_return_if_fail (link->next != NULL);

              link->next = queue->head;
              if (queue->head)
                    queue->head->prev = link;
              else
                    queue->tail = link;
              queue->head = link;
              queue->length++;
            }

            void
            g_queue_push_tail (GQueue  *queue,
                                               gpointer data)
            {
              g_return_if_fail (queue != NULL);

              queue->tail = g_list_append (queue->tail, data);
              if (queue->tail->next)
                    queue->tail = queue->tail->next;
              else
                    queue->head = queue->tail;
              queue->length++;
            }

            void
            g_queue_push_tail_link (GQueue *queue,
                                                            GList  *link)
            {
              g_return_if_fail (queue != NULL);
              g_return_if_fail (link != NULL);
              g_return_if_fail (link->prev != NULL);
              g_return_if_fail (link->next != NULL);

              link->prev = queue->tail;
              if (queue->tail)
                    queue->tail->next = link;
              else
                    queue->head = link;
              queue->tail = link;
              queue->length++;
            }

            gpointer
            g_queue_pop_head (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, NULL);

              if (queue->head)
                    {
                      GList *node = queue->head;
                      gpointer data = node->data;

                      queue->head = node->next;
                      if (queue->head)
                            queue->head->prev = NULL;
                      else
                            queue->tail = NULL;
                      g_list_free_1 (node);
                      queue->length--;
                      printf("First in line is %s\n",data );
                      return data;
                    }

              return NULL;
            }

            GList*
            g_queue_pop_head_link (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, NULL);

              if (queue->head)
                    {
                      GList *node = queue->head;

                      queue->head = node->next;
                      if (queue->head)
                            {
                              queue->head->prev = NULL;
                              node->next = NULL;
                            }
                      else
                            queue->tail = NULL;
                      queue->length--;

                      return node;
                    }

              return NULL;
            }

            gpointer
            g_queue_pop_tail (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, NULL);

              if (queue->tail)
                    {
                      GList *node = queue->tail;
                      gpointer data = node->data;

                      queue->tail = node->prev;
                      if (queue->tail)
                            queue->tail->next = NULL;
                      else
                            queue->head = NULL;
                      queue->length--;
                      g_list_free_1 (node);

                      return data;
                    }

              return NULL;
            }

            GList*
            g_queue_pop_tail_link (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, NULL);

              if (queue->tail)
                    {
                      GList *node = queue->tail;

                      queue->tail = node->prev;
                      if (queue->tail)
                            {
                              queue->tail->next = NULL;
                              node->prev = NULL;
                            }
                      else
                            queue->head = NULL;
                      queue->length--;

                      return node;
                    }

              return NULL;
            }

            gboolean
            g_queue_is_empty (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, TRUE);

              return queue->head == NULL;
            }

            gpointer
            g_queue_peek_head (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, NULL);

              return queue->head ? queue->head->data : NULL;
            }

            gpointer
            g_queue_peek_tail (GQueue *queue)
            {
              g_return_val_if_fail (queue != NULL, NULL);

              return queue->tail ? queue->tail->data : NULL;
            }

            ###main.c####

            int main(int argc, char *argv[])
            {
                    STRUCT_MSG test;
                    printf("MsgBuf Valusse is ::");
                    g_queue_create(1);
                    g_queue_create(2);
                    PostMessageQ(1,4,"testmesg",8);
                    PendMessageQ(1,&test);
                    printf("MIAN MsgBuf Value is :: %s\n",test.msgBuf);
                    PendMessageQ(2,&test);
                    printf("ENd of main");
                    return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an awful lot of copy/paste of the GQueue API, mixed with some new functions using a "channel" parameter, but named the same way as real GQueue functions, which is a terrible idea.

Finally, it seems the error is at the very end of the block of code you gave us. You call PendMessageQ, but you have posted no data in that queue. Hence, you try to get pop a value from that queue, but only get a NULL pointer, which you try to copy. And you get a segmentation fault in the memcpy for that.

Next time, use a debugger to find that out, and please provide a code that compiles, which was not the case here.